# Do the incorporeal swordsmen created by the Legion of Sentinels spell appear in midair?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, area-of-effect

*Player's Handbook II* 116 has the spell *legion of sentinels* which has an area of 10 foot radius emanation. An excerpt of the spell text says:

> A ghostly, incorporeal swordfighter appears in each square covered by this spell’s area [...]

I understand that playing D&D in 3 dimensions might be an exercise in futility, but given that spell areas are 3 dimensional, and the swordfighters are incorporeal, does the spell fill squares that would be in the air as well as those on the ground?

Put a slightly different way, does the spell create only twelve incorporeal swordfighters, or, depending on the location of the origin of the spell, up to thirty-two swordfighters; some on the ground, many in the air?

Comment: Related: [How do I handle targeting and areas of effect in 3-D?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/166539/how-do-i-handle-targeting-and-areas-of-effect-in-3-d)

Answer (score 2):

## Only twelve fighters appear

The rules describe aeras for spells in squares, not in cubes. They always talk about an area (2 dimensions), not a volume (3 dimensions).

The description of a sphere for example says:

> A sphere-shaped spell expands from its point of origin to fill a spherical area.

Technically, it would need to say the spell fills a spherical *volume*, but since the majority of combat happens on the ground and a two-dimensional battle grid, to speed up and simplify play, the rules assume you only care about two dimensions.

You can see the same attitude in how distances are measured:

> When measuring distance, the first diagonal counts as 1 square, the second counts as 2 squares, the third counts as 1, the fourth as 2, and so on.

This does only approximate the actual distances, it is a simplification to speed up play.

#### But what about fireball?

Now, while they say that, it is common practice to account for the areas of spells like [fireball](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/fireball.htm) in three dimensions, and also affect creaturs that fly above the ground if they are low enough.

You could argue the same treatment should apply to these illusionary warriors. Especially because these warriors are described as ghostly and incorporeal, and incorporeal creatures such as [ghosts](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/ghost.htm) often can fly.

**A technical argument against this** could be that a typical warrior would be larger than 5 feet in height, and since creatures in combat need space and cannot overlap, you at the very least could only create half of the number of warriors ... or you would need to create dwarf-sized warriors.

**A gameplay argument against this** is that this quickly gets too complicated to support flow during play. You end up bogged down [calculating volumes, instead of playing out an exiting battle](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/196600/if-a-twilight-cleric-uses-the-steps-of-night-feature-to-fly-up-do-the-areas-of/196602#196602). (See also this [in depth Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/166539/how-do-i-handle-targeting-and-areas-of-effect-in-3-d) of how to handle 3D distance in 3.5e, the mere length of which gives you a good idea of what you are getting yourself into.)

All that said, if both you and your DM think it should work, and you should be able to summon a ball full of dwarf-sized spectral swordfighters, go and have fun with it.

Comment: I don't buy the 'more than 5 feet' space argument. Medium creatures take 5' space... in combat.

Comment: @Chemus, you could also argue that they are incorporeal, so who cares if they overlap? You are right, medium creatures take 5x5 feet floor area. And you can indeed have medium sized creatures that are less than 5 feet tall, such as dwarves. If you want to get into 3D however, it might mean dealing with the fact that some creatures are taller than 5 feet.

Comment: RE: "Technically, it would need to say the spell fills a spherical volume…." And, equally technically, it would seem to need to say the spell fills a *circular area*, right? I mean, the phrase *fill a spherical area* is—technically—very weird. (That'd be, like, somehow *filling the surface area* of a sphere, which hurts my brain to such a degree that I can't imagine it's anywhere near the intended reading.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan, yes, agree. It would have been better to use on of those, and explain the construct being a simplification explicitly.  If they had chosen the wording of circular area, we otherwise would be discussing how it then can affect anyone standing on top of that area.

Comment: @HeyICanChan it’s not weird at all: a volume is what fills a manifold surface (like the surface of a sphere). It’s just like air fills a balloon.

Comment: @fectin Although I earned a D, Mr. Walker gave me a C in geometry because he was retiring and didn't care. With that in mind, I think Groody's point is that 3D things must say volume and 2D things must say area, so for this spell sphere means circle. I dislike this because I think it unfairly judges English majors by math standards and because it says sphere, too, and why not assume that it means instead sphere, right? That said, I'm okay with the answer because it means that the illusion that's created does not look super dumb with weird Matryoshka doll illusion swordsmen floating in space.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I understand his point, but he’s wrong in several ways. First, the surface of a volume is an area. So, anything that “fills an area”, where the area is a manifold, IS a volume. Second, it’s plain what is meant. “Area” is only strongly distinguished from “volume” in some contexts, and plain English is not one of those contexts. So, overall it’s plain what was meant (pick a ball, which gets fiery), and both the hyper-pedantic and plain meaning agree.